# sql split one row to multiple rows based on number of columns available

Tags: sql

Looking for an optimized solution, considering source table will have thousands of records.

**Source Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StageINV](
    [InvNo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Cost1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [AM1] [money] NULL,
    [Cost2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [AM2] [money] NULL,
    [Cost3] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [AM3] [money] NULL,
    [Cost4] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [AM4] [money] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

INSERT [dbo].[StageINV] ([InvNo], [Cost1], [AM1], [Cost2], [AM2], [Cost3], [AM3], [Cost4], [AM4]) VALUES (N'3435', N'12345', 4000.0000, N'23456', 600.0000, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[StageINV] ([InvNo], [Cost1], [AM1], [Cost2], [AM2], [Cost3], [AM3], [Cost4], [AM4]) VALUES (N'3467', N'54545', 2000.0000, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[StageINV] ([InvNo], [Cost1], [AM1], [Cost2], [AM2], [Cost3], [AM3], [Cost4], [AM4]) VALUES (N'3477', N'23456', 18000.0000, N'21414', 67800.0000, N'21567', 34500.0000, NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[StageINV] ([InvNo], [Cost1], [AM1], [Cost2], [AM2], [Cost3], [AM3], [Cost4], [AM4]) VALUES (N'3488', N'75698', 9000.0000, N'23235', 9800.0000, N'23434', 8967.0000, N'33455', 45445.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[StageINV] ([InvNo], [Cost1], [AM1], [Cost2], [AM2], [Cost3], [AM3], [Cost4], [AM4]) VALUES (N'3499', N'45678', 75.0000, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

**OutPut Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MainInv](
    [InvNo] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Cost#] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [AM#] [money] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Data should look like below (Providing insert script)

```
GO
INSERT [dbo].[MainInv] ([InvNo], [Cost#], [AM#]) VALUES (N'1-3435', N'12345', 4000.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[MainInv] ([InvNo], [Cost#], [AM#]) VALUES (N'2-3435', N'23456', 600.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[MainInv] ([InvNo], [Cost#], [AM#]) VALUES (N'3467', N'54545', 2000.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[MainInv] ([InvNo], [Cost#], [AM#]) VALUES (N'1-3477', N'23456', 18000.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[MainInv] ([InvNo], [Cost#], [AM#]) VALUES (N'2-3477', N'21414', 67800.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[MainInv] ([InvNo], [Cost#], [AM#]) VALUES (N'3-3477', N'21567', 34500.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[MainInv] ([InvNo], [Cost#], [AM#]) VALUES (N'1-3488', N'75698', 9000.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[MainInv] ([InvNo], [Cost#], [AM#]) VALUES (N'2-3488', N'23235', 9800.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[MainInv] ([InvNo], [Cost#], [AM#]) VALUES (N'3-3488', N'23434', 8967.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[MainInv] ([InvNo], [Cost#], [AM#]) VALUES (N'4-3488', N'33455', 45445.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[MainInv] ([InvNo], [Cost#], [AM#]) VALUES (N'3499', N'45678', 75.0000)
```

Comment: Does the source table have fixed number of columns (not rows)?

Comment: Yes... It has fixed number of columns... But they might not have values in all columns (i.e. it might have null value) As given in sample source insert script...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be as simple as

```
INSERT [dbo].[MainInv]
([InvNo], [Cost#], [AM#])

SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY InvNo ORDER BY [AM#]) AS myID
FROM
(
SELECT Inv1, Cost1, AM1
FROM dbo.StageInv
UNION ALL
SELECT Inv1, Cost2, AM2
FROM dbo.StageInv
UNION ALL
SELECT Inv1, Cost3, AM3
FROM dbo.StageInv
UNION ALL
SELECT Inv1, Cost4, AM4
FROM dbo.StageInv
) A
```

OR you can use `unpivot`

```
SELECT [InvNo], [Cost#], [AM#]
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY InvNo ORDER BY [AM#]) as myID
FROM 
(SELECT [InvNo], [Cost1], [AM1], [Cost2], [AM2], [Cost3], [AM3], [Cost4], [AM4]
FROM dbo.StageInv
) SRC
UNPIVOT
( [AM#] FOR AMS IN (AM1, AM2, AM3)
) C
UNPIVOT
( [Cost#] FOR CostS IN (Cost1, Cost2, Cost3)
) M
WHERE RIGHT(AmS, 1) = RIGHT(CostS, 1)
```

If you can edit desitination table structure, I would **recommend** to use a **row identifier** in destination table. So in future when you have to troubleshoot you can easily find from which column the data came from. (Is it from Inv1 or Inv2 or Inv3). $0.02

Comment: Is it a most optimized solution? also need rank- for InvNo  incase of multiple record for same InvNo...

Comment: Updated the solution with the unpivot method and rank #.

Comment: Unpivot solution looks good..... Can you pls explain what InvS is refering for?  WHERE RIGHT(InvS, 1) = RIGHT(AmS, 1)
AND RIGHT(AmS, 1) = RIGHT(CostS)